# How to validate a login in Azure SQL databases

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to validate a login for a user before installation of our software. They have the option to use either integrated security or sql login. This login is not and should not be in the sysadmin role, but that is beyond the scope of this question.

This should in my opinion be as easy as composing a connection string without a "Initial Catalog" and validate the login. This should connect to the users default database and we can make sure the connection was ok.

This is not the case when it comes to Azure SQL databases. Ordinary users normal dont have a valid default database since its set to master. Users dont have access to master.

```
sqlcmd -U xxxUser -S xxxdatabases.database.windows.net
Password: Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : The server principal "xxxdatabases" is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'xxxdatabases'..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Cannot open user default database. Login failed..
```

I might use an administrative account to check if the users have access to any of the existing databases and connect the user to that database. But that feels like a stupid solution and perhaps in conflict with our own EULA since we are not allowed to connect to random databases.

Does anyone have a tip on how to check a login on Azure SQL Databases?

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the database on the command line, and you'll connect directly:

```
sqlcmd -U xxxUser -S xxxdatabases.database.windows.net -d DatabaseName
```

Logins in Azure SQL Database don't have a default database, as a single connection cannot switched between databases like on a regular SQL instance.

Comment: Hi, and thanks. But that's just the thing. Our databases are not created yet because this is our validations check before the installation. There may be other databases we could connect to, but they are not ours. We do don't officially know other database names. We may use a sys admin account to find out what databases the user have access to, but it seems like a risky and perhaps illegal way to go.

Comment: If the principal is used to create your database, then it must be a user in the Master database and a member of the dbmanager role.  So you can just connect to Master.

Comment: No, our installer needs a sysadmin/dbmanager account to install. But we also need a account to run our application. That account must not be a dbmanager. That would be bad practice. This user will be added as a datareader/datawriter to the new database at some point in the installation. But at this point of installation we only want to validate the login and make sure the user running the installation entered correct credentials. That seems impossible in an Azure database environment since the database are not created yet.

Comment: I don’t see why you want to validate the application account before installation.  That account should be created as a contained database user during the installation.

Comment: Yes, unless the user account already exists as a login. We can get some weird behavior if we create a contained database user with the same name as an existing login. Especially if the user enter "wrong" password. You will end up with 2 credentials with different passwords and an unpredictable behavior when you login (depending on initial catalog). But it should work for now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/security-best-practices-with-contained-databases?view=sql-server-2017#creating-a-user-that-duplicates-a-login